# ms access openform where no data

Tags: ms-access

I have a frmA, based on qryA.
Button btnOpenfrmB on frmA opens another frmB, based on qryB.
But this frmB includes some unbound textboxes, with data from qryC, i.e. 
=DLookUp("Field";"[qryC]";"[ValueC] = " & [ValueB]). If qryB has no data (records), Dlookup fields return errors and opening frmB, which includes these textboxes, ends with an error. I understand this behaviour of frmB (there is no value B, that's why an error), but HOW CAN I AVOID IT and correctly open frmB for entering the first record ? When qryB has at least one record, everything works OK.

Thanx in advance

Duski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Nz` function if Field don't have, for instance 0 values:

```
=DLookUp("Field";"[qryC]";"[ValueC] = " & Nz([ValueB],0))
```

or `iif` function if Field can contain any value:

```
=iif(IsNull([ValueB]),"",DLookUp("Field";"[qryC]";"[ValueC] = " & [ValueB]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sergey, that was it !

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please mark it as answered, it will help others.